# Duplicating a function with an empty function for extensive inline documentation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to replicate Java's interface doc style by adding inline documentation to interface functions using *"blank"* functions in a different file.

Here's what I'm going for:

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func myFunction(_ message: String) {
        // Code here...
    }

}
```

**extension ViewController** <sup>(separate file with all my documentation)</sup>

```
extension ViewController {

    /**
      A very
      very, very,
      very, long
      inline documentation
    */
    func myFunction(_ message: String) {}

}
```

As of right now, I am stuck with files like this:

[image: Current state of code]

Comment: on iOS the interface = protocol, and what's the question?.

Comment: If you need to write too much documentation for a method then chances are that the method is too complicated and should be refactored into several methods

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to separate *definition* of functions (and their documentation) from actual implementation. You are mostly on the right path, but instead of `extension ViewController`, define a protocol, which requires that a conforming type is `UIViewController`:

```
protocol MyViewController: UIViewController {

    /**
      A very
      very, very,
      very, long
      inline documentation
    */
    func myFunction(_ message: String)

}
```

And then

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyViewController {

    func myFunction(_ message: String) {
        // Code here...
    }

}
```